# Sencha Touch 2.1 creating common class for AJAX request

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I have two doubts
  1)I am using sencha touch 2.1 for my application. And i want to create a common class for AJAX request because i am going to call from many controllers. Now my question is inside which directory(like model,store,controller) the common class for AJAX will come.And how i refer that class in app.js
 
  2)I want to set some configs like common url,text,etc for my app. How can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `Ext.Ajax` is a singleton class of [Ext.data.Connection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection), so you can already use it throughout your application without creating many instances.

2) As stated in the `Ext.Ajax` [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax), you can simply set `Ext.data.Connection` configs on the `Ext.Ajax` instance.

```
Ext.Ajax.setUrl('defaultUrl.json');
Ext.Ajax.request({}); // will use the above URL
```

You can get a list of all the available configs by looking at the [Ext.data.Connection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) class reference.